# Android activity transition on list view item click

Tags: android

How can i impliment slide etc.. animation transition when i open new activity by listview item click ?

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = null;
            // global string to class
            selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            if (selectedValue.equals("item1")) {
                                    // ^^^  use any item value here you want
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }

            else if (selectedValue.equals("item2")) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), aactivity4.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

santoash kumar answer is correct. If you struggle on R.anim.layout resource here an animation code work like how other chat application work(slide animation) when you click on the listview item.

Add those into your anim resource

R.anim.push_left_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

R.anim.push_left_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-20%" android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

R.anim.push_right_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-20%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    </set>
```

R.anim.push_right_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%" android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

In the activity1 or any activity you will like to perform this animation while it launch,add this code  after your set `setContentView()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
    //rest of your code include setContentView();
}
```

Now you will find a problem when you try to navigation back to your listView activity either with pressing the back button or click on the view which represent the back button the animation still seem to be the default animation so do this when you try to end your current activity.

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_right_out);
```

For the back button pressed use this code.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in,R.anim.push_right_out);
    }
```

If the animation I provide doesn't suit the animation you desire you can try to make your own custom animation from this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

Comment: Intent intent = null;
                // global string to class
                String selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (selectedValue.equals("item1")) {
                                          
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

Comment: this is my main activity

Comment: @WAQARALAM did you really read my whole answer? As I say put the overridePendingTransition() under your setContentView() which you wan to start not under where your activity start.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity1);  ....................................................................................................................................................................................................@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }\n\n....HOW TO I APPLY HERE.....

Comment: i was implementing that on wrong place  now,,,i have done it,,,,,thanks again

Comment: Can you help one more time .I have a navigation drawer main activity and a search view above list view .what I want is that when I scroll up the listview action bar gets hidden and both the list and search view shift above providing more space to user (same as used by Google chrome etc..)

Comment: @WAQARALAM open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_in);
```

hold and fade in will be animation xmls