# Open and Close transition animation to each activity

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I have a listview to open activities by switch method.In this case how can i apply activity open and close transition animation to each activity?

```
String selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

switch (selectedValue) {
    case "item1": {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
Use this line after startActivity();
right_in - anim to start layout
right_out - anim to close layout

Dont forget to swith on animation in developer setting!!

Comment: I'm using switch method....nothing is changing after inserting the line

Comment: Do you enable animation in developer setting?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exitanim);` after your `startActivity()`.

Comment: I'm using switch method....nothing is changing after inserting the line ..........startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in,R.anim.push_right_out);
                        break;

Comment: Try just startActivity()

Comment: Just wrap it in if statement SDK>16.

Comment: then it shows IF is replaceable with switch statement

Comment: It is a suggestion not an error. Your code will compile just fine.

Comment: if (selectedValue.equals("item1")) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_right_out);
                } else if..........................#### nothing is changing #####here below is link of animation i am using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536918/android-activity-transition-on-list-view-item-click/41537425?noredirect=1#comment70298402_41537425